# Selecting Toggle Button with only Classes to identify the toggle button with Selenium & Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am attempting to toggle a button on an existing html file that is online. I change some of the names of the files to not give away the website I am working on. I know there is a way to do this if the dropdown-toggle has a title or id. However, for this html file there are only classes. Is there a way to click on the toggle button with an html file with this structure?

```html
<li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><b>Name</b><strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="file.php">File1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="file2.php">File2s</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="file3.php">File3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="file5.php">Add</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="file6.php">search</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='dropdown-toggle']"))
# Or if it is not working.
button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-toggle='dropdown']"))
```

I think you are trying to select `<a>` with class name `dropdown-toggle`.